# Approximation of a Non Ideal Differentiator

Tags: operational-amplifier, error, phase, compensation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2czX9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above circuit is a differentiator, the op amp is assumed to be a single pole op amp, that is \$ A=\frac{wt}{s}\$

The transfer function is thus going to be that of a band pass filter. (2nd order)

My question though is, this is also a differentiator, so upto what frequency can this be approximated to be a differentiator.

Had it been an ideal op amp, it'd simply be a high pass filter. Now that we consider it to be non-ideal there must be a certain frequency upto which it can act as a differentiator, however, I have no idea on how to calculate that. Maybe using Phase/Magnitude errors?

Comment: The answer depends on the desired operating frequency range (values of R1, R2, C1).  Of course, R2/R1 should be as large as possible and R1C1 as small as possible.

Comment: The overall function of this circuit is high pass, not band pass.  This is assuming ideal opamp and the like.

Comment: Something fun to notice is that a circuit will behave as a differentiator as long as you have -20dB/decade and -90 degrees phase shift. While this is true it's an integrator, basically, regardless of the total number of poles/zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less mathematically rigorous but hopefully easy to grasp way of thinking about this.

What you have from the left end of C1 to the output is a pure differentiator.  The only thing that makes the circuit not a differentiator is R1.  R1 working against C1 is a low pass filter, which undoes the effect of the differentiator.

This circuit is therefore a differentiator when R1 is "small" compared to C1.  Put another way, the differentiator part of this circuit dominates below the frequency where the R1-C1 low pass filter becomes significant.

The frequency rolloff of a R-C filter is 1/2ΠRC.  In your case, at frequencies well below that, the low pass filter is effectively not there in that it simply passes its input signal to the output.  At frequencies well above the rolloff, the attenuation is proportional to the frequency divided by the rolloff frequency.

The answer as to what frequency range this circuit acts like a differentiator depends on what error you can tolerate.  The R-C filter action never completely goes away with lower frequency.  It only approaches that.  Only you can say how little effect is little enough.

Comment: Olin Lathrop - typing error (differentiator vs. integrator)? For a "small" R1 vlaue we have an nearly ideal differentiator. However, it will be not stable - therefore the series resistor R1.

Comment: @LvW: Oops.  Fixed.

Comment: Olin Lathrop - look at the 2nd line (integrator) and the 3rd line as well as the 7th line (lowpass).

Comment: @LvW: Doh!  Fixed the remaining (I think) "integrator" to "differentiator".  However, the "low pass filter" part is correct.  R1-C1 form a low pass filter.  A Bode plot of that filter would be flat line at 0 dB to the rolloff frequency, then sloping down at 20 dB/decade to the right of that.  The differentiator, in contrast, has a rising frequency response at 20 dB/decade.  These combine to make a flat frequency response past the R1,C1 roloff frequency.  Below that, the differentiator dominates.

Comment: OK - I know what you mean. Regarding the node between R1 and C1 we have a lowpass behaviour - and the signal at this node sees a ideal differentiator. Both effects cancel each other - and we hav a flat magnitude for low frequencies.

Comment: @LvW: The flat response is at *high* frequencies, when both the low pass filter and the differentiator are active.

Comment: Yes - you are right. I had the inverse feedback factor in my mind because this response determines the selection of the upper corner frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You can work through the transfer function (Vout/Vin) by assuming no current is flowing into the op-amp inputs.  Thus:

[image]

Plug in your function for the op-amp gain into A and the solve for Vout/Vin.  You can then plot the gain and phase response as a function of frequency and compare to an ideal differentiator.

Comment: Good idea, however assuming no current flowing into the inputs is a strong simplification, especially when taking into consideration input capacitances. You can use this equation for establishing general behaviour of the circuit, but I wouldn't count on getting the corner frequency right by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @Chris Hansen That's correct, but I believe there's no need to re-invent the wheel. I'd rather use your return ratio expression in some well established feedback theory context

Comment: @FelixS Including some extra non ideality, input capacitance, but also output impedance is indeed possible, but I believe a step by step approach to give a better learning curve. So start as simple as possible (first setp with ideal opamp already done?) and then increase your model complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I think, also in this case, you can treat the opamp as ideal because all real properties (finite input and output impedances, frequency dependent gain) play a minor role only.

The "cross-over" frequency (unity magnitude) is app. at **w1=1/R2C1**. The upper corner frequency (magnitude flattens out at a value of (R2/R1) is app. at **w2=1/R1C1**. Because of stability of the feedback loop, it is important that this frequency (w2) is well (at least by a factor 6) below the frequency wo where the loop gain magnitude is unity.  This requirement gives you another equation for selection of w2.

The frequency wo can be found by using the constant gain-Bandwidth product (transit frequency wt) : GBW=wt=wo*(1+R2/R1). From this, we can derive the requirement

**w2 << wo=wt/(1+R2/R1)**.